# Ratio of consecutive coefficients Power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Hi if I have two power series $\Sigma a_nx^n$ and $\Sigma b_nx^n$ and they verify $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim_{\infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$ can I conclude that $\Sigma a_nx^n \sim_{\infty} \Sigma b_nx^n$ ?

Edit:

- I assume the two power series have a convergence radius infinite
- When I write $\Sigma a_nx^n \sim_{\infty} \Sigma b_nx^n$ I mean $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \sim_{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$$

understanding that the equivalence is for $x\to \infty$

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you mean that partial sums $\sum_1^N$ are equivalent as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: Take the series
$$
\sum_0^\infty\left(\frac 1{2}\right)^n,\qquad \sum_0^\infty n\left(\frac 1{2}\right)^n
$$
You have 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}
$$
since both have limit $1/2$. Both series are convergent, with different sums.

Comment: My first power serie is a polynom, we have relation between $a_{n+2}$ and $a_n$ (the polynom has either only even term or only odd terms) therefore we can evaluate $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}$. The second power serie is $e^{x^2}$ which has an even power serie expansion ($b_0$, $b_2$, ...). We notice that $\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_n}$ is the same at infinity as $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}$. Can we conclude the polynom is equivalent to the exponential at infinity ? It is based on this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6Ma-zn4Olk&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60cspQn3N9dYRPiyVWDd80G&index=67

Comment: @GReyes To answer your question: no, I mean they are equivalent at x going to infinity

Comment: Say the first series is $e^x$ and the second is $x\cdot e^x$. Then the ratios of subsequent coefficients are equivalent, but the functions, er, well...